# Is it possible to include a program project and a Wix project both in a Visual Studio Solution?

Tags: visual-studio, mono, wix

For example, I use Visual Studio to create a mono game project in the solution, and I add another wix project that

when I hit "build solution", the mono game project being build, and wix project build a installer directly afterward.

In this way, I don't need to separate my project everywhere, because I just want some more additional options with One-Click installer.

If I can use Wix, I can customize the installer, but how?

After search for some time, I found this

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html

But, I would like to put two projects in a same solution folder, rather than two separate solution folder. This way, if I change the path, will the link just broke up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Simply add a reference to the project from your WIX project.

Note that with project references, you can use variables in your wxs files. For example if your game project were `DavidWong.MyGame`:

```
<File Id="MyGame.exe" 
      Name="$(var.DavidWong.MyGame.TargetFileName)"
      Source="$(var.DavidWong.MyGame.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
```

See [the documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks you, but is that matter if I change my build config from x86 to x64 or Debug to Release?

Comment: No, the variable follows the current configuration

Comment: Okay, I will try. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done ( project reference and $(var.ProjectName.TargetDir) and so on ) but in my experience there are a few reasons not to:

1) When a new version of Visual Studio comes out you might be stuck if a new version of WiX is not yet released to support that version of Visual Studio.  I've seen this several times and currently you'd have to run a beta build of WiX v3.10 if you wanted to support Visual Studio 2015.

2) All developers now have to install WiX or get error messages that some projects couldn't be loaded.

3) Some developers will complain that they don't want "setup" code in their .NET solution.  I think this is a thin complaint but I kinda get it.

What I like to do is have an application solution and an installer solution.  I use postbuild copy commands and MSBuild publish profiles to stage content in a "deploy" folder that models the deployed system and then use that reference that structure in my wix code.

Comment: Thanks for help, I'll take into consideration in the future.